# Postgres SQL select query syntax

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this SQL statement, I am getting a syntax error:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  user_table
  INNER JOIN (
    klass_table
    LEFT JOIN room_table
  )
```

Syntax error is vague, it says:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; it seems the error is around:
>   ')' at line 8

Perhaps I am missing an `ON` clause?

Comment: Perhaps, what happened when you added one? Doesn’t really make sense to have a left join without one

Comment: Yeah it works when I add an ON clause to the LEFT JOIN.  It doesn't look like I need an ON clause for INNER JOIN, tho.

Comment: Yes, their function is different so their requirements are also different.

Comment: You **do** need a join condition (specified with `ON`) for an inner join. Those parentheses are pretty much useless by the way: `from user_table join klass_table on ... left join room_table on ...` works just as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not mentioned the columns on which you are doing the inner join.So basically you are missing the "ON" keyword for both the joins.

Comment: Yeah the ON keyword only seems to be necessary for the LEFT JOIN, not necessary for the INNER JOIN

Comment: @rakim: the `ON` condition is needed for all joins except `cross join`